# Make computed property available globally

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm using Vue 2 and in one of my components I've defined a simple computed property to filter through an array of objects:

```
  computed: {
    filteredPlans: {
      get() {
        let res = [];
        if (this.query.length > 1) {
          this.plans.forEach(p => {
            if (JSON.stringify(p).includes(this.query)) res.push(p);
          });
          return res;
        } else return this.plans;
      },
      set() {
        return this.plans;
      }
    }
  },
```

I want to using the same logic in 5 other components as well. So, my question is should I just duplicate the code on other compoents or make it available globaly, also how do i do that?

Comment: I'd use a mixin, or make this filtered items a part of a self-contained component.

Comment: I would use a store, move plans into store and make getters for it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a `Mixins` file and add the computed property in it.

Mixin named `test-mixin`

```
export default {
  computed: {
    filteredPlans: {
      get() {
        let res = [];
        if (this.query.length > 1) {
          this.plans.forEach(p => {
            if (JSON.stringify(p).includes(this.query)) res.push(p);
          });
          return res;
        } else return this.plans;
      },
      set() {
        return this.plans;
      }
    }
  },
}
```

This can be reused in any component by importing the `mixin` file like follows

```
import testMixin from 'test-mixin';
export default {
  mixins: [testMixin]
}
```

Comment: If i do this, how would I access filtered plans inside my components? Also, I want to be able to pass the query and the array.

Comment: If it is common in all your components, then you can add it into the Mixin file.